# How to run startup command for a nodejs, express js project on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-devops

I am using **Azure DevOps** for my app. I am not sure how to set up a startup command for the project. If I will add it to the task in the created pipeline, it gives an error, maybe because the process will never end.

Actually, I am able to run npm install and create the artifact, but I will need the App a StartUp command to execute **Node server.js**

So, below is an image showing a post-deployment action I have added. It does the job but at last, it says deployment failed. I am hoping there is a better process to trigger the **npm start** command because I can't see any logs as I see on a local server with this command.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I will add it to the task in the created pipeline, it gives an error, maybe because the process will never end.

This is correct, if you try to run the startup command on your application within a pipeline it will start a process that will run until the Agent Job times out (60 minutes by default for Microsoft-hosted agents, 360 minutes for self-hosted agents).

- Here's Microsoft's documentation on agent job timeouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#timeouts

You will want to avoid running the startup command within your pipelines to avoid tying up your agents.

If you have code that needs to be executed within the application start-up to complete your build/deployment, I'd recommend moving into your webpack.config.js or your package.json's commands.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for clarifying that you're trying to run the startup command **within an Azure App Service on startup**. You won't want to use the **Post Deployment ACtion**, that feature is designed for altering the contents of your deployment after the deployment is successful.

To get your node.js app to start, within your **package.json** file make sure it has **"start"** under **"scripts"**:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "your start script here",
  }
}
```

The Azure App Service will, by default, look for "start" within your "package.json" file at the root of your App Service content. If you have a custom startup file, you can configure your app service to use it with the following command:

```
az webapp config set --resource-group your-resource-group --name your-app-name --startup-file "path/to/custom-startup.json"
```

Here is a link to Microsoft's documentation on configuring a Node.js application's startup within an App Service:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-npm-start

Comment: I am really thankful for having you help me. Actually, if I add the code to the build command this will also not end and keep going until the timeout comes. Let's say I just need the **"node server.js"** command to run after my **artifacts** are successfully delivered to the Azure service.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for clarifying, I've updated my answer with more details regarding how to get a node.js application started within an Azure App Service.

Comment: Got it. I have to build another **NodeJs, Express App,** and I am able to run it successfully. I did check the **Logs** for this app. It works fine. However, I don't know why it's not working for the app on which I have to spend a month of time. Is there any reason? The logs are not showing and the response is **"You don't have permission to view the directory files."**

Comment: Glad to hear that your App Service is starting. If you don't mind, please mark the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: With regard to your latest issue, I'd need to see the full logs and app service configuration to determine why it's taking to start now that it's able to execute the startup script. I'd recommend posting a new question so you can post the full details.

Comment: Got it. I will do that.

Comment: Any idea on how to set up the start-up file for a Windows-based app service? I saw the command for Linux-based app services is 'az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --startup-file "<filname-with-extension>"', but I don't know if it'll work on Windows-based app services.

Comment: @Gabriel For Azure App Service (Windows) you just need to provide a proper `web.config` file along with your startup file (and other files), https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/